How to Cache a Method Returning a Map in Quarkus with Redis?
I'm trying to cache a method in my Quarkus application that returns a Map<String, PlanAttrUnified>. I'm using Redis as the caching provider. However, I'm encountering issues configuring the cache properly in my application.properties file.
Here is the method I wnat to cache:
public <T extends BaseTaskEntity> Map<String, PlanAttrUnified> fetchAllPlanAttr(
        @CacheKey T baseTask, boolean raiseError) {
    // my Method logic 
}

And here's how I've configured the cache in application.properties:
quarkus.cache.redis.attribute-cache.cache-name=yourCacheName
quarkus.cache.redis.attribute-cache.expire-after-access=96H
quarkus.cache.redis.attribute-cache.value-type=java.util.Map<java.lang.String, your.package.PlanAttrUnified>

However, this configuration doesn't seem to work. When I run the application, the method is not being cached as expected.
Can someone please guide me on how to correctly configure caching for a method returning a Map in Quarkus using Redis? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.
log message:
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
    [error]: Build step io.quarkus.cache.redis.deployment.RedisCacheProcessor#determineValueTypes threw an exception: jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: Unable to determine the value type for 'detailed-panel-jobcards' Redis cache. An appropriate configuration value for 'quarkus.cache.redis.detailed-panel-jobcards.value-type' needs to be set
    at io.quarkus.cache.redis.deployment.RedisCacheProcessor.determineValueTypes(RedisCacheProcessor.java:97)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$3.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:849)
    at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:256)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2513)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1538)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)


    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.throwBootFailureException(QuarkusTestExtension.java:638)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.interceptTestClassConstructor(QuarkusTestExtension.java:722)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
    [error]: Build step io.quarkus.cache.redis.deployment.RedisCacheProcessor#determineValueTypes threw an exception: jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: Unable to determine the value type for 'detailed-panel-jobcards' Redis cache. An appropriate configuration value for 'quarkus.cache.redis.detailed-panel-jobcards.value-type' needs to be set
    at io.quarkus.cache.redis.deployment.RedisCacheProcessor.determineValueTypes(RedisCacheProcessor.java:97)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$3.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:849)
    at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:256)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2513)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1538)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)

    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.runAugment(AugmentActionImpl.java:334)
    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.createInitialRuntimeApplication(AugmentActionImpl.java:251)
    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.createInitialRuntimeApplication(AugmentActionImpl.java:60)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.doJavaStart(QuarkusTestExtension.java:224)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.ensureStarted(QuarkusTestExtension.java:605)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.beforeAll(QuarkusTestExtension.java:655)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
    [error]: Build step io.quarkus.cache.redis.deployment.RedisCacheProcessor#determineValueTypes threw an exception: jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: Unable to determine the value type for 'detailed-panel-jobcards' Redis cache. An appropriate configuration value for 'quarkus.cache.redis.detailed-panel-jobcards.value-type' needs to be set
    at io.quarkus.cache.redis.deployment.RedisCacheProcessor.determineValueTypes(RedisCacheProcessor.java:97)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$3.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:849)
    at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:256)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2513)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1538)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)

    at io.quarkus.builder.Execution.run(Execution.java:123)
    at io.quarkus.builder.BuildExecutionBuilder.execute(BuildExecutionBuilder.java:79)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.QuarkusAugmentor.run(QuarkusAugmentor.java:160)
    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.runAugment(AugmentActionImpl.java:330)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: Unable to determine the value type for 'detailed-panel-jobcards' Redis cache. An appropriate configuration value for 'quarkus.cache.redis.detailed-panel-jobcards.value-type' needs to be set
    at io.quarkus.cache.redis.deployment.RedisCacheProcessor.determineValueTypes(RedisCacheProcessor.java:97)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$3.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:849)
    at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:256)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2513)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1538)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)

I also realised that I deleted 'detailed-panel-jobcards' from everywhere and still get an error that i ahve to set a value for it.
This is my cache annotation:
@CacheInvalidate(cacheName = ATTACHMENTS_CACHE_NAME) 
public void invalidateGetAttachmentLinks(long layoverId) {} 

and before every method that I want to cache I put:
@CacheResult(cacheName = ATTACHMENTS_CACHE_NAME)


Is there anything useful in the logs? By the way, quarkus.cache.redis.attribute-cache.value-type=java.util.Map<java.lang.String, your.package.PlanAttrUnified> is not going to work, you need to remove the generics.

@geoand Alright, I just added the log output to my question.

@What do your caching annotations look like?

@CacheInvalidate(cacheName = ATTACHMENTS_CACHE_NAME)
public void invalidateGetAttachmentLinks(long layoverId) {} and before every method that I want to cache I put:     @CacheResult(cacheName = ATTACHMENTS_CACHE_NAME)

Please update the description with that information as the code in comments is not really readable.

Alright, check it out again

Any chane you can attach a sample application that I can try myself?
